# Acess internet from remote machine via SSH session and proxy

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, proxy, tunnel

Computer A is connected to internet through http/https proxy (proxy-server.com:111). Computer B does not have access to internet but I can SSH to Computer A.

```
Computer-B -> COMPUTER-A -> PROXY -> Internet
```

I am using proxychains in Computer-B to set up SOCKS4/5 proxy at 127.0.0.1:9050.

```
Computer-A$ ssh -D 9050 127.0.0.1 -t ssh -R 9050:127.0.0.1:9050 Computer-B
```

I checked with wget and it works with proxy specified:

```
Computer-B$ proxychains4 wget http://google.com -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=http://proxy-server.com:111
```

Not all applications have this option to specify proxy in command line. I need to include one more proxy while SSH-ing from Computer-A. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Try looking at the HTTP_PROXY environment variable

Answer (score 0):

I just need to set this in Computer-B :

`export https_proxy=https://proxy-server.com:111`

`export http_proxy=http://proxy-server.com:111`